# Can't connect to SVN from Subclipse in Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm trying connect to a SVN repository from Sublipse. I have followed this steps:

1. Open **SVN Repository Exploring** perspective
2. Select *New > Repository Location...*
3. Enter repository url.
4. Enter SVN access credentials
5. The message *Operation in progress...* appears indefinitely

The only thing that could suppose a problem is the proxy, but I don't think so because:

- Eclipse is configured to use the proxy. I installed Subclipse from the Eclipse Marketplace.
- I can access to my repository from any browser, even from the Eclipse browser view.
- I tried it from Fedora 23 and Ubuntu 16.04.
- In Windows systems I have no problem.
- I configured **SVNKit** as SVN interface client in preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resulted a problem of domain resolving. When I tried to put the respository's IP, I was able to access.

So, I did ping tests and I realized that my machine didn't can resolve the domain succesfully.

Once I fixed the network settings in the file **/etc/nsswitch.conf** (@doep answer from https://superuser.com/questions/704785/ping-cant-resolve-hostname-but-nslookup-can), I could access from Subclipse without problems.